# Swift memory leak?

Tags: swift, memory-management, memory-leaks

When I check my application for memory leaks I found a memory leak when I call this function

```
class func displayAlertWithTitle(title: String, message: String, onView view: UIViewController?) {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

        if let parentView = view as UIViewController? {
            parentView.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }
```

more specifically in `parentView.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)`
Anyone can explain me please why is this happening?

Comment: Do you ever dismiss the alert controller?

Comment: @Tim I dismiss the alert controller with the OK button when is showed